# Why would I be getting `Error: write EPROTO` when making an HTTPS request in an Electron app?

Tags: node.js, https, electron

I've been pounding my head against the wall for days on this so I am turning to the smart folks at Stackoverflow to help. Here's the deal:

### System Details

- Node Version (can't be changed due to Electron dependencies): v4.1.1
- Electron Version: v0.34.3
- OS Version: Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F1021)

### Issue Description

I'm building an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app that has to communicate with my company's application server. The server connection has to go over HTTPS. I'm using Node's built-in [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) module. When making a request to the server I'm getting the following error:

`{ [Error: write EPROTO]
  code: 'EPROTO',
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write',
  address: undefined }`

I've done a ton of Googling on this and most everything I've found points to proxies but I'm not using a proxy. I've tried the following:

- Setting `rejectUnauthorized: false` in the options hash
- Modifying the `secureProtocol` option (no results)
- Attempting to set the `--tls-cipher-list` (no idea what I'm doing there)

I can make the request over `curl` without issue. Unfortunately, I can't post the actual URL I'm making requests to.

### Sample Code

Here's some sample code (Coffeescript) that illustrates the issue:

```
https = require 'https'

options = {
  host: '[Application URL]'
  path: '/'
  method: 'GET'
  port: 443
}

options.agent = new https.Agent(options)

callback = (response) ->
  str = ''
  console.log response
  console.log "STATUS: #{response.statusCode}"
  console.log "HEADERS: #{JSON.stringify(response.headers)}"
  response.setEncoding 'utf-8'
  response.on 'data', (chunk) -> str += chunk
  response.on 'end', -> console.log str

makeRequest = ->
  req = https.request options, callback
  req.on 'error', (err) ->
    console.log err
  req.end()

makeRequest()
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue? Is it a Node issue or something with the configuration of the application server? This bug is killing me and preventing me from hitting a milestone at work so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried another server?

Comment: Yeah. We have a pilot server that I am able to connect to but, unfortunately, I don't have access to either to try and determine the difference between them. The pilot server isn't running HTTPS so I didn't have this issue.

Comment: u may want to have a look of this https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3692

Comment: The server may not accept https connection, have you tried http

Answer (score -7):

To resolve this issue you are required to set https-proxy, which can be done with the following command:

```
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

Comment: It has actually solved my issue when I got the following error:
Error: write EPROTO 805BEC47F87F0000:error:0A0000C6:SSL routines:tls_get_more_records:packet length too long:ssl/record/methods/tls_common.c:655:

thank you